# Show chapter name in fancyhdr when no section is available

Tags: fancyhdr, report

The following code shows only section names in the headers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Uno}
\section{Ducks}
\lipsum

\chapter{Dos}
\lipsum

\chapter{Tres}
\section{Frogs}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However some of my short chapters (like Chapter 2 in the example) don't have sections in them. In this case, the header on the page is empty. If there is no section, I would like the chapter name to appear at the same place.

How could I achieve this?

Please note that I don't want both chapters and sections to show. I want section title to show as a priority, and if they're not available, I want the chapter title.

Comment: `\markleft`? `\markboth`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `\chaptermark` (called by `\chapter`) only sets the `\leftmark`. You can make it set the `\rightmark`; a section will take precedence over it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{}{\MakeUppercase{%
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \@chapapp \ \thechapter. \ \fi #1}}%
}
% if you don't want the word `Chapter', use the following
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
%  \markboth{}{\MakeUppercase{%
%    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \thechapter. \ \fi #1}}%
%}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Uno}
\section{Ducks}
\lipsum

\chapter{Dos}
\lipsum

\chapter{Tres}
\section{Frogs}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```